# Mysql DB select from table where field statement java

Tags: java, jdbc, spring-jdbc

I'm trying to query database using java, I don't understand the problem with this function. it return a garbage values.

I just want to retrieve from a MySQL database the values matching the first_name.

```
public List<Customer> select(String cusDB) {
    return jdbcTemplate.query(
            "SELECT id, first_name, last_name FROM customers WHERE first_name= cusDB",
            (rs, rowNum) -> new Customer(rs.getLong("id"),
                    rs.getString("first_name"), rs.getString("last_name")));
}
```

Comment: I'd be very surprised if this would return "garbage values", I'd sooner expect an exception about an unknown column `cusDB` or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just have the name of a Java parameter in the query string. You need to provide the parameter to the query explicitly. To do this, change your code to:

```
public List<Customer> select(String cusDB) {
    return jdbcTemplate.query(
            "SELECT id, first_name, last_name FROM customers WHERE first_name= ?",
            new Object[] { cusDB },
            (rs, rowNum) -> new Customer(rs.getLong("id"),
                    rs.getString("first_name"), rs.getString("last_name")));
}
```

That is, you introduce a parameter placeholder (`?`) in the query string, and add an array of parameter values to the method call (one value for each parameter placeholder in your query). See also the [`JdbcTemplate` documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#jdbc-JdbcTemplate) and documentation of [`JdbcTemplate.query(String sql, Object[] args, RowMapper<T> rowMapper)`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#query-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object:A-org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper-).

Answer (score 3):

You can use two ways the first is to concatinate your query with your first_name that you want to search:

```
"SELECT id, first_name, last_name FROM customers WHERE first_name= '" + cusDB + "'"
```

Second use `PrepapredStatement` like so :

```
"SELECT id, first_name, last_name FROM customers WHERE first_name= ?"
st.setString(1, cusDB);
```

But i don't see any sign about PrepapredStatement so you can learn here [Prepared Statement doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)

**Edit**

Like @André Schild said in the comment :

*you are vulnerable to SQL injections, for example a firstname with `'; delete from customers; //will remove all customers from your database`. Always(tm) use prepared statements*

Comment: Don't use the first version, you are vulnerable to SQL injections, for example a firstname with `'; delete from customers; //`will remove all customers from your database. Always(tm) use prepared statements

Comment: yes @AndréSchild for that i suggest to use PreparedStement, i think he miss some thing about String concatenation for that i post the first one thank you so much